# Firebase Remote Config Security

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-security, firebase-remote-config

does anyone know what version of TLS protocol is used in Firebase Remote Config and is it https connection while connecting?

Answer (score 2):

It uses the HTTPS stack that Android provides on the device via the [HttpsURLConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html) implementation.  So, it's impossible to know all the details for sure, unless you also know what's on the specific device you're dealing with.